# unresolved external symbol _pathCombineW()

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

having this error although shlwapi.h has been included..

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__PathCombineW@12 referenced in function "bool __cdecl Fs::_pathCombine(wchar_t *,wchar_t * const,wchar_t * const)" (?_pathCombine@Fs@@YA_NPA_WQA_W1@Z) NewZeV  C:\Users\mike\Desktop\workspace\NV\fs.obj   1

code snippet

```
bool Fs::_pathCombine(LPWSTR dest, const LPWSTR dir, const LPWSTR file)
{
LPWSTR p = (LPWSTR)file;
if (p != NULL)while (*p == '\\' || *p == '/')p++;
return CWA(shlwapi, PathCombineW)(dest, dir, p) == NULL ? false : true;
}
```

how do I ago about solving this linking error? I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: Also note that your question title is not what the error message says.

Comment: sorry man, but I don't know why you think the question is not what the error says, I'm having a linking error, unresolved external symbol, i noticed the duplicate alright before posting, but still i can't get how to apply a solution to my case!
I will like to specify that I don't get the error using codeblocks but only MVS

Comment: Title: *"unresolved external symbol _pathCombineW()"* - Error message: *"unresolved external symbol __imp__PathCombineW@12"*. Anyway, the duplicate has the solution to your problem.

Comment: which is ? is not like I want you to do my dirty job for me, just indicate the right direction..which of the solutions please ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to link with `shlwapi.lib`.

Comment: thank you, will learn the -"basic things"

Comment: @RbMm, thanks, will learn the "basic things".